# DrawString with highlighted text in my asp net program using mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, graphics, system.drawing, drawstring

i'm making a web app which writes text on a series of images.Now the text must be highlighted Yellow. I'm using DrawString , but with it i cannot make this operation. My code is:

```
g.DrawString( text...", fontSize, fontColor, 200, 320, textAlign);
```

How can i make this text highlighted?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the DrawString overload that takes a brush, pass it a HatchBrush?

Answer (score 0):

```
var sz = g.MeasureString(text, fontSize);
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, new Rectangle(200,320,sz.Width, sz.Height);
g.DrawString( text...", fontSize, fontColor, 200, 320, textAlign);
```